# Add Browserify as the last step in gulp task's transformations

Tags: gulp, ecmascript-6, browserify

I have a gulp task that transforms ES6/ES7 using Babel, does the uglifying, concatenation and eslinting. However, when I finished writing my gulp task I realized that the `require` function wouldn't work in the browser, so now I need to add browserify transformation to my task. Having added browserify, I get an error.

Here's how my gulp task looked like without browserify:

```
gulp.task('js', () => {
    gulp
        .src('./js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(eslint())
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        .pipe(eslint.failAfterError())
        .pipe(babel({
                plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
                presets: ['es2015']
            })
        )
        .pipe(uglify({ mangle: false }))
        .pipe(concat('all.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./production/js/'));
});
```

When I added browserify it started to look like this:

```
gulp.task('js', () => {
    // Clean tmp/js directory
    gulp
        .src('./tmp/js/*.js')
        .pipe(clean());

    // Transform all js and throw it into tmp/js directory
    gulp
        .src('./js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(eslint())
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        .pipe(eslint.failAfterError())
        .pipe(babel({
                plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
                presets: ['es2015']
            })
        )
        .pipe(uglify({ mangle: false }))
        .pipe(concat('all.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./tmp/js/'));

    // Browserify the all.min.js file and throw it
    // into ./production/js directory
    browserify('./tmp/js/all.min.js')
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('all.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./production/js'));
});
```

And here're some of my imports used in the task:

```
import babel from 'gulp-babel';
import clean from 'gulp-clean';
import uglify from 'gulp-uglify';
import source from 'vinyl-source-stream';
import browserify from 'browserify';
import concat from 'gulp-concat';
import eslint from 'gulp-eslint';
```

My first gulp task worked just fine, as it only did the transformation from ES6 to browser-compatible js.

But my second gulp task gives me the following error:

> events.js:85
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>               ^ Error: Cannot find module 'babel-runtime/helpers/typeof' from
>   '/home/denis/WEB/Eclipse/workspace/BlackJack/Application/BlackJack/servletBlackJack/WebContent/tmp/js'

The error is thrown exactly while executing the `browserify(...)` block.

---

Could you help me to make this work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `extension` switch from [here](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify):

> Consider files with specified EXTENSION as modules, this option can used multiple times.

They you will probably need to update your gulpfile this way:

```
 browserify({
    entries: './tmp/js/all.min.js',
    extensions: ['.js'] // wanna add '.jsx' ?
    })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('all.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./production/js'));
```

Maybe babel task too:

```
    // ...
    .pipe(babel({
            plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
            presets: ['es2015'],
            extensions: ['.js'] // wanna add .jsx?
        })
    // ...
```

Try command line:

```
browserify --extension=.js src/**/*.js -o bundle.js -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 ] ]
```

Also, see [my article](http://ro31337.github.io/Building-TDD-React-boilerplate-with-ES6-series-Part-1/) with code example at the bottom of the page.